# Performant way to clear excessive old data in a text file

Tags: c#, performance, file

I have some text files that I need to be able to write to on the fly, and quite often. These files can get pretty big in size, but the text inside them can be completely different between two iterations.

This means that text can be shorter than it previously was. Which, if i wouldn't clear the old data first, would end up in a mix of the old data being appended at the end of my new data. As indicated by the MSDN docs.

> If you overwrite a longer string (such as "This is a test of the OpenWrite method") with a shorter string (such as "Second run"), the file will contain a mix of the strings ("Second runtest of the OpenWrite method").

However the docs do not specify a way to remedy or even prevent this from happening.

Currently i'm doing the following:

```cs
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    file.Write(dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.Length);
}
```

Where i empty the contents of the existing file using `File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty)` and then write the new contents to the file.

However it feels like a waste to have to go over the entire file twice (First to clear it, and then to write the new data to it).

Is there a way where i can overwrite the old data with my new data, and only go over the "left over" data and clear that, without going over the entire file twice?

It doesn't necessarily have to use `Stream.Write`. Any alternative that gets the job done and is faster is acceptable.

---

**Results**

After running 100.000 iterations of writing 2441 kb of data (and clearing all old data) 5 times on different machines, the following results came out:

- My original method found above took `4.75589 ms` on average.
- Anderson Pimentel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54461174/8628766) using `WriteAllBytes` took `4.28946 ms` on average.
- **fastest** Dark Falcon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464037/8628766) using `file.Write` and truncating took `4.14433 ms` on average (and is the fastest/most consistent with this).
- `File.Delete` the old file and creating a new file using `FileStream.Write` took `5.31883 ms` on average.
- MeJustAndrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464474/8628766) doing the above but multithreaded took `8.12726 ms` on average. (Though i have to admit this could very well be because of poor implementation by me, I am in no way very experienced in multi threading)

note that these results apply to *my* [implementation](https://github.com/RemyRM/WriteSpeedsTest) and hardware. Results may vary on different hardware.

Comment: Have you tried comparing performance with File.Delete and recreating a new file to write all text ? This is an interesting question. I would have imagined there would be an option to override the entire file when writing all text :)

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes should do what you want in one line.

Comment: @Joe Thanks! I didn't know `WriteAllBytes` is also a thing. It looks alot cleaner *and* it is faster. Running a small test case downloading a 6.5mb text file it actually already ran 2ms faster (105 ms vs 103 ms). (I see Anderson just edited his answer to use Bytes aswel)

Comment: @remy_rm you can accept Anderson Pimentel's anwser.

Comment: @Joe Although it appeared to be faster on a small scale, it actually looks less performant when dealing with bigger files. I've included a test case in my original question.

Comment: @remy_rm - looking at the implementation with ILSpy, there is a minor difference: `File.OpenWrite` will open the file with `FileShare.None` , while `File.WriteAllBytes` will use `FileShare.Read`.  Odd that the default behavior would be different, it might explain the small difference you're seeing.

Comment: I would go for a multi-threaded, multi-file approach. Have a thread writing to a new file then another thread deleting the old one and so on. It may be worth testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend truncating the file:

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    file.Write(dataToWrite, 0, dataToWrite.Length);
    file.SetLength(dataToWrite.Length);
}
```

You should test whether this performs better than writing a new file, deleting the old file, and renaming the new file to the old name.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it seems to be the fastest (and most consistent!) method of writing to a file and wiping the old contents

Answer (score 1):

You could just write:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, dataToWrite);
```

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten.

Comment: You can use `WriteAllBytes` method. I updated the answer.

Comment: Although I think it looks way more elegant for sure. This seems to actually be slower. After running a basic tests 5 times (copying around ~185MB of data 10 times, into a 192MB file) it is about 9% slower, although the times are more consistant. (test + results https://pastebin.com/p3DaqVBB )

Comment: @remy_rm No need for tests. It is [implemented](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,972) almost the same way as yours.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, a multithreaded approach would look like this:

```
class FileWriter
{
    private int index;
    private string fileName = "file.txt";
    private readonly object obj = new object();
    private string FileName { get { lock (obj) { return fileName + index; } } }

    public void Write(string content)
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            int deleteIndex = index;
            new Thread(() => DeleteOldFile(deleteIndex)).Start();
            index++;
            new Thread(() => File.WriteAllText(fileName + index, content)).Start();
        }
    }

    public string GetFileContent()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            return File.ReadAllText(FileName);
        }
    }

    private void DeleteOldFile(int fileNumber)
    {
        var fileToBeDeleted = fileName + fileNumber;
        if (File.Exists(fileToBeDeleted))
            File.Delete(fileToBeDeleted);
    }
}
```

Note: I don't guarantee for the correct behavior of this code, as I have not tested it.

Comment: this approach is indeed good for when I need to work multiple files at once! However it loses the gain it gets from multithreading when a single file gets edited a couple of times as it can't write until the deletion is done.

Comment: @remy_rm the thing is that you start writing in the same time as deletion happens so it may be faster than a single overwriting of the file..

Comment: Hmm, as is it throws an error `The process cannot access the file <file> because it is being used by another process`. I suppose i could edit it it so it deletes the old file, while creating the new file with a temp name, and then rename that to the old file name. ( I now see your example incremented the index to achieve this, I would just need to add something that restores to the original filename). Though I think this would create a race condition if the writing/renaming happens before deletion finishes? (fairly new to multi threading, so please correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @remy_rm I guess the exception is thrown because of the index which is the same when sent to the deleting thread as in the writing thread (because it is captured in a closure) , and it gets incremented before the deletion starts. I believe that holding it to another variable would work. I will edit the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Yep got it to work now! Gonna run some tests on a bigger sample size now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @remy_rm I'm glad to hear it works! Let me know how your tests turn out.

Comment: Falcon's answer seems to be the fastest and most consistent across multiple file sizes. Due to limited time i'm not able to run as much tests/gather as much data as i want. But hope to be able to form some data tabels backing this up at some point.